# A light-weight library to expose SQL database tables over HTTP with querying?

Tags: linux, open-source, python, postgresql

Would you be able to recommend a simple open-source library/tool to run in Linux, which would serve a REST-like API basically serving the content of SQL databases (in Postgres) over HTTP with friendly URLs? Python preferred, but not mandatory.

e.g. if you had a database with two tables:

```
employees (id, name, city, dep_id)
departments (id, name)
```

I would like to easily send HTTP requests like:

```
GET http://$HOST/employees?city=Paris
GET http://$HOST/employees?dep_id=4&city=Berlin,Paris
GET http://$HOST/departments?name=Legal,Finance
```

etc. I am flexible with whatever syntax needs to be used for URLs. But the goal is to avoid manual work of mapping these tables through ORM, then mapping that to URLs, etc. Ideally no programming needed at all (but allowed if I wanted to add a custom output format, etc.)
Also I understand this tool could only offer `SELECT` with only limited `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: BTW the adminer.php and myphpadmin programs offer a full web based GUI.  However, not access like above.

Answer (score 4):

You may try [nginx](http://nginx.org) HTTP server in conjunction with [ngx_postgres](https://github.com/FRiCKLE/ngx_postgres) module. `ngx_postgres` allows `nginx` to communicate with `PostgreSQL` database. Your basic requirements are satisfied as far as I see:

- No programming needed. Only `ngx_postgres` configuration shall be specified to map URLs to DB queries.
- At least SELECT with WHERE clause support (see examples on `ngx_postgres` web page).
- `PostgreSQL` as a RDBMS.
- `HTTP` protocol.
- `nginx` is lightweight software.

You didn't specify response format you want to return to the clients, but `ngx_postgres` supports JSON.

Answer (score 2):

RestifyDB (http://restifydb.com) is one solution. Its opensource and can be used free (unless you need patching etc for which there is a commercial version available. Though i have not used slash DB (https://www.slashdb.com/) is another solution which works on similar lines.

Answer (score 2):

[Sandman2](https://github.com/jeffknupp/sandman2) does exactly what you want, in python and advertises itself as `Automatically generate a RESTful API service for your legacy database. No code required!`

It uses SQLAlchemy for database interactions (and support any of its many supported DB) and offers not only a REST API but also a decent web Admin Interface.

Once, configured you should be able to issue queries such as `http://$HOST/employees?city=Paris` and similar though it may not support `http://$HOST/employees?dep_id=4&city=Berlin,Paris` where you ask for multiple values at once.... To be tested!